# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView$SavedState;

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView$SavedState;

Issue while open an activity from one of the bottomNavigationView Fragments.

**My HomeFragment**

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    view.buttonFeed.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(getActivity(), FeedActivity::class.java))
    }
    return view
}
```

**My TestActivity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feeds)
}
```

**My BottomNavigationView code in my DashboardActivity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)
    try {
        bnView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_home -> {
                    loadFragment(HomeFragment())
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.nav_notification -> {
                    loadFragment(NotificationFragment())
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.nav_search -> {
                    loadFragment(SearchFragment())
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.nav_account -> {
                    loadFragment(AccountFragment())
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
            }
            false
        })
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    loadFragment(HomeFragment())
}
```

And my error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.foodshots.app, PID: 19568
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView$SavedState;
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.onSaveInstanceState(BottomNavigationView.java:553)
    at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:15872)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3335)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341)
    at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:15855)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2101)
    at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1493)
    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(ComponentActivity.java:83)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:589)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatActivity.java:510)
    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1423)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1322)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:4720)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3993)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4058)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap25(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1591)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$SavedState
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.onSaveInstanceState(BottomNavigationView.java:553) 
    at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:15872) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3335) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341) 
    at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:15855) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2101) 
    at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1493) 
    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(ComponentActivity.java:83) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:589) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatActivity.java:510) 
    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1423) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1322) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:4720) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3993) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4058) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap25(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1591) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/customview/view/AbsSavedState;
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.onSaveInstanceState(BottomNavigationView.java:553) 
    at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:15872) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3335) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341) 
    at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:15855) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2101) 
    at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1493) 
    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(ComponentActivity.java:83) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:589) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatActivity.java:510) 
    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1423) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1322) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:4720) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3993) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4058) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap25(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1591) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.customview.view.AbsSavedState" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.foodshots.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.foodshots.app-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.onSaveInstanceState(BottomNavigationView.java:553) 
    at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:15872) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3335) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3341) 
    at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:15855) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2101) 
    at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1493) 
    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(ComponentActivity.java:83) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:589) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatActivity.java:510) 
    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1423) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1322) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:4720) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3993) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4058) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap25(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1591) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `androidx`, then try to add this dependency to your module level `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```